# Read webpage for parsing

Tags: 2010

Using SP2010, I am trying to pull in a webpage to parse the data. We currently have a VBScript which does the work on it's own, but I am trying to get it integrated into our SP site. In VBS, we are using the following method to pull in the data:

```
Set objHTML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
objHTML.Open "GET", "http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/", False

objHTML.send

strHTML = objHTML.responsetext
```

I can pull a page from the SP farm, but not external from it. I have converted it to JavaScript, but get the same error, which is: permission denied. I realize this is probably a setting on the server side of things, but I have no control on this and it will not be changed. So, the question is, what else might I be able to use to pull the web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is perform a NTLM authentication exchange with SharePoint...
What you can do is get fiddler and see what information is exchanged before SharePoint actually serves the page. Another way would be to put this web page parsing application within a ASPX web application page. and turn on windows authentication it will do the NTLM challenge for you and allow you to access the SharePoint page... Another route which may be beyond the scope of your question but any data that SharePoint Displays on page is more than likely accessible through a webservice or CSOM (CLient Object Model)..

Comment: Thanks Joseph ... you have given me a lot of avenues to look at. There should be a way forward in here somewhere :D

Comment: Do you need help using webservices I could point you in the right direction... I bet that will help

Comment: HAHA! Yes, I can use whatever help you can send my way. I appreciate your help :-)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx

Comment: This will show you how to access sharepoint data using silverlight or javascript in your case.

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. I will check this approach sometime today and let you know if our system is going to allow me to do it :D I appreciate your time.